# Is it possible to run sqlite3_exec() on another thread?

Tags: objective-c, sqlite

As the title states: is it possible to run the method `sqlite3_exec()` in another thread?

```
TBXMLSuccessBlock sBlock = ^(TBXML *tbxmlDocument) {
    xmlArray = [NSMutableArray array];

    if (tbxmlDocument.rootXMLElement)
        [self fillArrayWithXmlContents:tbxmlDocument.rootXMLElement];

    for (int i = 0; i < xmlArray.Count; i++)
        sqlite3_exec(db, "Query that uses xmlArray values", 0, 0, 0);
};
```

As you can see this is a block that is being executed on another thread.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I refer you to the [sqlite3 FAQ](http://www.sqlite.org/faq.html#q6):

> Is SQLite threadsafe?
>
> Threads are evil. Avoid them.
>
> SQLite is threadsafe. We make this concession since many users choose
>   to ignore the advice given in the previous paragraph. But in order to
>   be thread-safe, SQLite must be compiled with the SQLITE_THREADSAFE
>   preprocessor macro set to 1. Both the Windows and Linux precompiled
>   binaries in the distribution are compiled this way. blah blah blah

So I would say "yes", it should be OK.

Comment: The "blah blah blah" actually contains rather important information ;)

Comment: @nmaier Yeah I was hoping anyone interested would follow the link and I felt it was too much text to include in my answer.

Comment: I have followed the link and read the whole part, that was exeactly what I needed

Comment: if it is thread safe, does that mean 2 threads (using different database connections) can write simulataneously the the database file ?

Comment: @krishna222 Yes, that's what it means.

Answer (score 1):

The answer would be "maybe yes, maybe no".

I suggest you read the [SQLite FAQ entry on thread-safety](http://www.sqlite.org/faq.html#q6) and check with the rest of your code and the sqlite3 library you link against.